# Android Studio resource file Copy-Paste issue for Devnagari font

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

In my application, I have few devnagari text which I want to copy as a text and create a resource text in string file. But when I copy text from pdf or word and paste it in strings.xaml file the text gets changed. My source for this text is a pdf file which has many resource text which i want to use as a resource text. I have the TTF font installed on my machine and in pdf/word or text file it shows correctly but when paste in Android Studio xml resource file it gets corrupted.

How I can get the same text in resource file so that I can use it in my application. Below is the sample invalid text which I tried to copy and paste in resource file is shown.

Incorrect Text displayed in string resource file is : **ZVy Z**

Correct Text which i want is : **नूतन**

Please note this correct text is created from different source (Google Translate).

Thanks in advance,

*IamHuM*

Comment: First, paste the word in notepad and then copy from the notepad and paste to android studio.

Comment: Show me your string.xml and pdf file

Comment: If I copy text from my source pdf to notepad or word then initially text is displayed incorrectly like this 'ZVy Z' but when i change font to any Devnagari font in notepad or word then it shows the correct devnagari text 'नूतन'. So i guess the problem is with default font of editor but not sure how to resolve this. Please correct me if I wrong. 

Below is the resource xml file:
================

'<resources>
    <string name="app_name">आर्थिक माहिती</string>
    <string name="app_newly_typed_text1">नूतन</string>
    <string name="app_copied_text_from_pdf">ZVy Z</string> 
</resources>'

Comment: One more information here on my issue: 

Fonts are embedded in the pdf file which i have installed on my laptop manually and its working. When i type any text or copy the text from pdf and then change the font in document then it shows the correct devnagari text.

Any clue?